# XML attribute access in AS3

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x

I have an xml file (loaded in with URLLoader) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <localizations>
        <words>
            <Brand us="Brand Here"></Brand>
        </words>
    </localizations>
    <world squareunits="100"></world>
</root>
```

Once loaded,what is the quickest way to access ***world.squareunits*** with E4X or just pure AS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var xml : XML = new XML( yourStringHere );
trace( xml.world.@squareunits );
```

Comment: booyah! I love stackoverflow. So much easier than wading through miles of blogs in search of esoteric xml parsing methods!

Comment: This is a great resourse if you have further XML questions

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_08.html